JavaScript Weight Input Validation Popup Triggering Multiple Times
I’m working on a weight tracking application using JavaScript, and I’m encountering an issue where the "Please enter your weight" alert appears when I try to save the weight. It seems like the saveWeight function is being triggered twice, causing the validation to fail the second time.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const formattedDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementById('currentDate').textContent = `Today's Date: ${formattedDate}`;

    const weightInput = document.getElementById('weightInput');
    const heightInput = document.getElementById('heightInput');
    const genderSelect = document.getElementById('genderSelect');
    const saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');
    const clearButton = document.getElementById('clearButton');
    const poundsOutput = document.getElementById('poundsOutput');
    const bmiWeightOutput = document.getElementById('bmiWeight');
    const bmiOutput = document.getElementById('bmiOutput');
    const bmiStatus = document.getElementById('bmiStatus');
    const ctx = document.getElementById('weightChart').getContext('2d');
    let weightChart = null;

    function loadSavedRecords() {
        const savedWeights = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('weightRecords')) || [];
        renderChart(savedWeights);
    }

    function saveWeight() {
        const weight = parseFloat(weightInput.value);
        
        // Check if the weight is valid before doing anything else
        if (weight) {
            let savedWeights = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('weightRecords')) || [];
            const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]; // Get the current date again
            
            savedWeights.push({ date: currentDate, weight });
            localStorage.setItem('weightRecords', JSON.stringify(savedWeights));
            loadSavedRecords();
            calculateBMI(weight);
            weightInput.value = ''; // Clear the input field after saving
        } else {
            alert('Please enter your weight');
        }
    }

    function renderChart(savedWeights) {
        const labels = savedWeights.map(record => record.date);
        const data = savedWeights.map(record => record.weight);

        if (weightChart) {
            weightChart.destroy();
        }

        if (data.length > 0) {
            weightChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Weight (kg)',
                        data: data,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 2,
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Date'
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Weight (kg)'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        }
    }

    function calculateBMI(weight) {
        const heightInMeters = heightInput.value / 100;
        const bmi = (weight / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters)).toFixed(2);
        bmiWeightOutput.textContent = weight;
        bmiOutput.textContent = bmi;

        let status;
        if (bmi < 18.5) status = "Underweight";
        else if (bmi < 24) status = "Normal weight";
        else if (bmi < 29) status = "Overweight";
        else status = "Obesity";

        bmiStatus.textContent = status;
    }

    function clearData() {
        localStorage.removeItem('weightRecords');
        loadSavedRecords();
        bmiWeightOutput.textContent = '0';
        bmiOutput.textContent = '0';
        bmiStatus.textContent = 'Unknown';
    }

    const confirmModal = document.getElementById('confirmModal');
    const modalClose = document.getElementById('modalClose');
    const cancelClear = document.getElementById('cancelClear');
    const confirmClear = document.getElementById('confirmClear');

    clearButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        confirmModal.style.display = 'block';
    });

    modalClose.onclick = function() {
        confirmModal.style.display = 'none';
    }

    cancelClear.onclick = function() {
        confirmModal.style.display = 'none';
    }

    confirmClear.onclick = function() {
        clearData();
        confirmModal.style.display = 'none';
    }

    weightInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
        const weight = parseFloat(weightInput.value);
        if (weight) {
            poundsOutput.textContent = (weight * 2.20462).toFixed(2);
        } else {
            poundsOutput.textContent = '0';
        }
    });

    saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveWeight);

    loadSavedRecords();
});

I have ensured that there are no duplicate event listeners attached to the save button.
The input field for weight is cleared after saving, but I believe the issue might be with how the weight is being parsed or the event listener itself.
Here’s the key part of my code related to saving the weight:
function saveWeight() {
    const weight = parseFloat(weightInput.value);
    
    // Check if the weight is valid before doing anything else
    if (weight) {
        let savedWeights = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('weightRecords')) || [];
        const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]; // Get the current date again
        
        savedWeights.push({ date: currentDate, weight });
        localStorage.setItem('weightRecords', JSON.stringify(savedWeights));
        loadSavedRecords();
        calculateBMI(weight);
        weightInput.value = ''; // Clear the input field after saving
    } else {
        alert('Please enter your weight');
    }
}

saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveWeight);


looks like you are binding the event listener to saveButton twice.

Please edit the code to create a minimal reproducible exampe, as a code snippet that includes test HTML. I reduced it  by removing code for local storage, modals, clear button, bmi calculation and drawing a chart, but did console log the saveWeights array. It worked perfectly. Basically in the MRE, remove anything whose removal doesn't fix the problem. Looking forward to your update.
